# Search bar blocked by navigation bar

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchbar

I'm trying to add a search bar to my UITableView. I dragged the Search bar and Search Display Controller to the top of my table and everything looks fine. However, when I click on the search field, the navigation bar and the search bar are jumbled together like this:

[image]

I tried setting the translucent field of the navigation bar to false and doing `self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone` but nothing has worked so far.

Comment: "I dragged the Search bar and Search Display Controller to the top of my table" Well, that's not how to do it. And UISearchDisplayController is dead anyway. Use UISearchController and puts its search bar into the table's header view in code.

Comment: I used UISearchController instead and get the same results. It looks like the search view is somehow behind the table view.